# How to create a photo roll website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm attempting to create a website that when someone uploads a picture, it appears on the homepage.

What language would be easier to use for this (javascript, PHP or other) and how would I go about creating this.

Comment: **language would be easier**, depending on your skills. and you need to work on some AJAX as well according to your requirement..

Comment: javascript for sure ... (AJAX) and then your preference for server side ... this question is to broad for S.O

Comment: i would write it in other, klingon perhaps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll probably go with javascript then on the frontend with AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular scripting languages of today which include Python, PHP, Javascript, and more; have robust libraries to support a whole lot of common operations such as image uploading and more.

A decision of whether PHP or Javascript is to be used, is entirely up to you. Since you are going to be the one coding it you should be comfortable with the language. Give a go at these programming languages and find which one suits you the best

If you were to ask me, I don't generally give crystalline answers to such vague questions, however I would recommend javascript as it seems that you aren't experienced with any language in particular as of yet. This will simplify your full stack development by allowing you to code in one language. Note this is a personal advise and could not necessarily be correct here.

-Relfor